# .net cycle of life of a page

Tags: asp.net, .net

I my PageLoad I call a method in asynchrone with

```
  new Action(() =>   { ... }).BeginInvoke(null, null);
```

Does the RequestEnd will wait all thread created in there 
Or my page will be render before the end of my asynchronous method (assuming it takes more of time)?

Comment: Comment rather than answer, but I've always been under the impression that running threads in ASP.NET is not a good idea, and won't work properly

Comment: it's done with safe lock, and a delay between two call to avoid somthing too much aggresive

Comment: @freefaller there is nothing particularly wrong with using multiple threads for *short* operations (once that will finish before end of request) with proper synchronization . Using `async`/`await` and `Parallel` namespace makes it much simple to write correct multithreaded code including ASP.Net.

Comment: And that's why I made it a comment rather than answer - thanks @Alexei

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Request.End` (or `Redirect`) ends request synchronously  and does *not* wait for any outstanding asynchronous request or additional threads.